# Triggering click with jquery on hidden input-file tag

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari, file-io

I am testing this idea of using a div on top of an invisible `<input type="file" />` so I can make a fancy file uploading button. I have seen some code around but was somewhat complicated. I thought of trying this idea of using jQuery to trigger the click of the input tag from its div container

Html:

```
<div id="container">&nbsp;Click Me!&nbsp;
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#container').click( function() {
        $('#file')[0].click();
    })
});
```

Although the code runs OK on Chrome and IE, it does not run on Safari and it has a funny problem with Firefox: it triggers the click twice! Any idea why this is so? jQuery is supposed to be cross-platform and I am puzzled.
Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/kostasd/C4sCs/1/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Kostas

Comment: The work around for this is not to hide the element, but instead give it a `display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:-9999px;`, then wrap it with a container that has `position:relative;overflow:hidden;width:somepx;`. **DO NOT USE display:none**. Then trigger your click; bam, cross-browsers support .

Comment: Thank's for the tip. I'll give it a try.

Comment: In the current version of Firefox it will also work with `display: hidden`

Answer (score 5):

The different Possible Solutions which I tried are

- **Using Visiblity:hidden; width:1px; for the File input element.**

> The jsfiddle for it is as follow
>   http://jsfiddle.net/C4sCs/36/

- **Using only the Css to call the file input click and not using jquery at all**

  ```
  #container {
  border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
  #file {  
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  opacity:0;
  display:block;
  }
  ```

> http://jsfiddle.net/C4sCs/42/

Comment: Don't wrap file input in a button element! Got me. Div works though.

Comment: This was causing problems for me as well. Thanks for the hint!